# Bootstrap slider does not update

Tags: bootstrap-slider

I am trying to use a Bootstrap slider with a custom handler. However, the value does not update when I move my slider.

HTML:

```
<input id="#ex6" type="range" data-slider-min="-5" data-slider-max="20" 
data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="3"/>
<span id="ex6CurrentSliderValLabel">Current Slider Value: <span 
id="ex6SliderVal">3</span></span>
```

JS:

```
var slider = new Slider("#ex6");
 slider.on("slide", function(sliderValue) {
document.getElementById("ex6SliderVal").textContent = sliderValue;
 });
```

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vw1G.png)

Comment: Make a jsfiddle. An image doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to add the `#` symbol to your id. The `#` symbol itself says you are referencing an ID.

```
<input id="ex6" [...] />
```

See also: CSS selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors

Comment: I get this when i change it: Uncaught ReferenceError: Slider is not defined

Comment: well, have you included the relevant libraries? If this solved this issue, you will probably want to accept this answer and open another question for the next issue.